# A binary wrap function

Tags: co.combinatorics

This question was inspired by [a card puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/84531).

Define a wrap function to take an $N$-bit number to another $N$-bit number by
"negating and reversing and wrapping leading bits" (this is just the simplest
way to cut a deck of cards with a $1$ on one side and a $0$ on the other side).
For example for $N=8$:

```
wrap(10101000, 1) = 01010000
wrap(10101000, 2) = 10100010
wrap(10101000, 3) = 01000010
wrap(10101000, 6) = 00101010
wrap(00101010,-6) = 10101000    [wrap(wrap(x,a),-a) = x]
wrap(10101000, 7) = 01101010
wrap(10101000, 8) = wrap(10101000,-8) = 11101010
wrap(10101000, 0) = 10101000
```

As Gerhard Paseman pointed out, the negative wraps (only $-6$ is shown above)
can be expressed as positive wrap iterates.  This leaves me wondering whether all of the positive wraps are needed for a minimal basis.

In other words, in the card puzzle example with $N=52$, can one of the $52$ positive wrap functions be expressed as a composition of the other $51$ positive wrap functions?  What about general $N$?

UPDATE: In random simulations for N=8, I found that wraps of 1 and 3 can be composed to generate wraps of 5 or 7 (but not 2, 4, 6, or 8).  Most surprisingly, I found that wraps of 1 and 2 can be composed to generate everything (i.e., all possible 10321920 "negate and permute transforms", which therefore include all wraps; e.g., 122122121212=3).  So, I'm guessing wraps of 1 and 2 can be composed to generate everything for N=52 also.  My questions basically become:

1. Is this two-wrap basis obvious/provable?
2. Can someone write out a composition for N=52 to form, for example, a wrap of 3?

Comment: More generally, with a bigger than b, wrap(wrap(x,a),-b) looks like something that leaves the first a-b bits alone. I think you have something that is a compositional basis for a larger set of functions. In fact I suspect the basis is functionally complete, and possibly minimal.  Actually,  wrap(x,-a) should be an iterate of wrap(x,a). Gerhard "Don't See A Proof Yet" Paseman, 2019.05.31.

Comment: What does "negating" mean in this context? How do you negate a positive number, and get a positive number out of it?

Comment: @Gerry, it means logical negation, an involution on the set {0,1}. Gerhard "Is Not New To Binary" Paseman, 2019.05.31.

Comment: @Gerhard I see what you mean about the iterate, so let me focus on just positive a and restate my question.

Comment: @Gerhard, thanks. I figured out I was parsing the instructions incorrectly. I thought it was negating and reversing the entire string, then wrapping leading bits, but it's only the leading bits that get negated and reversed.